# How to link two modules in shiny app (one using reactable and the other leaflet)?

Tags: r, shiny, module, r-leaflet, reactable

I have an app that renders some data using reactable and shows the same data in a map (using leaflet).

the table object is selectable and the selected rows are shown in the map.

when I clear the selection in the table (with an actionButton), I want the original map to render (with all data points).

Below is a working example with the quakes dataset.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("t"),
  actionButton(inputId = "clean", label="Clear selection"),
  leafletOutput("m")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$t <- renderReactable({
    reactable(quakes[1:10,],
    selection = "multiple")
  })
  output$m <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(quakes[1:100,]) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$clean, 
             list(  updateReactable("t", selected = NA),
               leafletProxy("m", data = quakes) %>%
                 addMarkers())
  )
  
  observeEvent(getReactableState("t","selected"),
     leafletProxy("m", data = quakes[getReactableState("t","selected"),]) %>%
       clearMarkers() %>%
       addMarkers()
   ) 
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

When I try to write the same app with modules, it does not work. Below is one of the many attempts.

I am trying to use modules, since this is part of a larger app, and it would make it much easier to manage...

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(reactable)

tUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    reactableOutput(outputId = ns("t")),
    actionButton(ns("clean"), label="Clear selection")
  )
}
tServer <- function(id, mapa){
  moduleServer(id,
      function(input, output, session){
        output$t <- renderReactable({
          reactable(quakes[1:10,],
                    selection = "multiple"
          )
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$clean, {
          list(
            updateReactable("t", selected = NA)#,
         #   leafletProxy(mapa(), data = quakes) %>%
         #     addMarkers())
        )})
      }
  )
}

mUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("m"))
  )
}
mServer <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session){
                  output$m <- renderLeaflet({
                    leaflet(quakes[1:100,]) %>%
                     addTiles() %>%
                     addMarkers()
                 })
                  m2 <- reactive("m")
  })}
##########################################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  tUI("tt"),
  mUI("mm")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ttt <- tServer("tt", mmm$m2)
  mmm <- mServer("mm")
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Any help, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have cross-talk between modules, you need to return reactive objects from one module and input it to the other module. Here, I've returned `clean` and `getReactableState` from the `tServer` module and input it to `mServer`. For an introduction to this concept, you might find [my tutorial on shiny modules](https://github.com/jonas-hag/structure_your_app) helpful.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(reactable)

tUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    reactableOutput(outputId = ns("t")),
    actionButton(ns("clean"), label="Clear selection")
  )
}
tServer <- function(id, mapa){
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session){
                 output$t <- renderReactable({
                   reactable(quakes[1:10,],
                             selection = "multiple"
                   )
                 })
                 
                 observeEvent(input$clean, {
                   list(
                     updateReactable("t", selected = NA)
                   )})
                 
                 return(
                   list(
                     clean = reactive({input$clean}),
                     selected_items = reactive({getReactableState("t","selected")})
                   )
                 )
               }
  )
}

mUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("m"))
  )
}
mServer <- function(id, clean, selected_items){
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session){
                 output$m <- renderLeaflet({
                   leaflet(quakes[1:100,]) %>%
                     addTiles() %>%
                     addMarkers()
                 })
                 
                 observeEvent(clean(), {
                   
                   leafletProxy("m", data = quakes) %>%
                     addMarkers()
                 }
                 )
                 
                 observeEvent(selected_items(), {
                   leafletProxy("m", data = quakes[selected_items(),]) %>%
                     clearMarkers() %>%
                     addMarkers()
                 })
                 
               })}
##########################################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  tUI("tt"),
  mUI("mm")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  ttt <- tServer("tt")
  mServer("mm", clean = ttt$clean, selected_items = ttt$selected_items)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was aware I had to return the objects from one module and call them from the other. It was a problem of getting the sintax right. I'm new to modules, so yes, I will follow your tutorial. Thanks again.